# How to write a select statement using a nested join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been learning how to use nested joins but I can't seem to get them working for my current database.

I have created these tables:
[image]

I want to first find out how many users have made at least one usage (they have some minutes in their account), created their account in 2016, and used an iPhone in 2013.
I've tried which is producing an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM USER
WHERE usage_count > 0
AND account_created <= ‘2016-12-31’
AND account_created >= ‘2016-01-01’
INNER JOIN PRODUCT
WHERE product = 'iPhone';
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN PRODUCT` ------ you're missing the columns to join `ON`

Comment: `JOIN` clauses have to go before `WHERE`.

Comment: There's no `usage_count` column in any of your tables, so what is `usage_count > 0` supposed to refer to?

Comment: @Barmar `usage_count` is in the user table

Comment: Oops, missed that. It would be better if you posted text instead of images, so we can use the browser's search function.

Comment: @Barmar got it let me try and make an edit. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to join USER and PRODUCT together - they don't have any columns in common. The USAGE table *does* have both `user_id` and `product_id` in it, so perhaps you need to include that in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query error out which is expected since you have two `WHERE` clause and `USER` is key word and shouldn't be used as identifier. I have escaped them using backtique better use a non key/reserve word as your column name. Your query should look like

```
SELECT COUNT(u.user_id) FROM `USER` u
INNER JOIN USAGE us on us.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN PRODUCT p ON us.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.product = 'iPhone'
AND u.usage_count > 0
AND u.account_created <= '2016-12-31'
AND u.account_created >= '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: `USER` is a keyword, but it's not reserved, so it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: You need to join with the `usage` table, since that's what links `user` and `product`.

Comment: You've got the wrong types of quotes around the dates (because you copied them from the question).

Comment: @Barmar, yes right it's key word. Change the wording in answer. Again I have just suggested the flaws in his posted query and not the actual query  that would work.

Comment: MySQL has so many keywords that are common words, it's hard to avoid using them as table and column names. E.g. everyone has a column named `password`.

Comment: Column names like `USER` or `DATE` can have something added to them which eliminates the conflict *and* improves comprehension - so instead of `USER` you might have `USER_NAME`, instead of `DATE` you might have `ADD_USER`, etc.

Comment: Why do you use `INNER JOIN USAGE` but only `JOIN PRODUCT` seems like terrible style -- since they are the same thing shouldn't you be consistent?

Comment: also `YEAR(account_created) = 2016` unless account_created is an index.