# Selecting columns from three tables using nested join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the following tables:

USER TABLE

```
user_id (primary key)
account_created (date)
email (varchar)
usage_count (number)
```

PRODUCT TABLE

```
product_id (primary key)
product (varchar) (values include “iPhone”, “Android”, “Windows”)
users_supported (number)
```

(users supported notes: some phones can support group calls up to 1000 users, some can only support normal calls of 2 users)

USAGE TABLE

```
usage_id (primary key)
product_id (foreign key)
user_id (foreign key)
usage_date (date)
purchase_call (number) (can be a 0, 2, 4, 6, or 10 min call)
usage_winnings (number) (when users use their minutes, sometimes they will randomly earn cash back)
computer_usage (binary value) (users can link the phone to a computer, and make calls through their computer, similar to google voice)
```

PAYMENT TABLE

```
payment_id (primary key)
user_id (foreign key)
payment_type (char) (either D or W)
 (D to deposit money to purchase minutes, or W to withdraw cash back bonus from usage_winnings)
payment_date (date)
amount (number)
```

I want to write a select statement that displays the following list:

1. Total minutes purchased for iPhone in 2016
2. Total minutes purchased for the other types of phones in 2016
3. The total amount the user received from usage_winnings EVER
4. % of calls made on computer for all phones in 2016 (to explain this some more, you can purchase minutes for an iPhone, then make a call with that iPhone through a computer, similar to Google Voice)
5. The last PAID usage date for a phone call (a 0 minute phone call, or a phone call shorter than a minute is considered free, so only values that include 2, 4, 6, or 10)
6. The net account balance in the user's account (deposits - withdraws)

With the following constraints: 
Have made at least one usage (they have some minutes in their account), created their account in 2016, and used an iPhone in 2013.

So far I have:

```
SELECT u.user_id, SUM(us.purchase_minutes), SUM(us.purchase_minutes), COUNT(us.usage_winnings), COUNT(us.computer_usage) / SELECT COUNT(us.usage_id), us.usage_date, pa.amount
FROM ‘USER’ u, ‘USAGE’ us, ‘PAYMENTS’ pa
INNER JOIN USAGE us ON u.user_id = us.user_id
JOIN PRODUCT p ON us.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN PAYMENT pa ON USER u
WHERE p.product_id = ‘iPhone’
AND u.usage_count > 0
AND u.account_created <= ‘2016-12-31’
AND u.account_created >= ‘2016-01-01’
```

So far I have the constraints down, but I am unsure how to list the information needed. In the case of point one `Total minutes purchased for iPhone in 2016` can I include a `WHERE` statement following the column name? I.E

```
SUM(us.purchase_minutes) WHERE p.product = 'iPhone'
```

I just started learning SQL so please forgive me if this is a basic question. I have asked a related question in this post: [How to write a select statement using a nested join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294553/how-to-write-a-select-statement-using-a-nested-join)

Here is a picture that hopefully paints a more detailed picture of the database 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsmoR.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a select statement using a nested join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294553/how-to-write-a-select-statement-using-a-nested-join)

Comment: @e4c5 I was told new question new post.

Comment: new question new post is very much right but this looks exactly like the old one to me. I would also recommend that you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be aware that we hate sql tabels and sample data being posted as images

Comment: what you have so far combines two different styles of joins.  very strange would def. give errors.

Comment: ogk, that's right; if it's new question then post it separately but instead of posting a long thread, do few things: link the previous related question -> post the table schema as text instead of images -> shorten your issues saying what have been done and what is that you are trying to achieve on top of it. If possible,  post some sample data as well.

Comment: @Rahul and e4c5 Thank you guys for your suggestions, I will try and edit my post to hopefully make everything more organized and concise.

Comment: also, **the answer *does not* require a nested inner join**

Comment: @Hogan made an edit to the title, thank you.

Comment: rofl -- it is also not a nested join.  I'm sorry to say... all you have here is some inner joins and a group by.  Unless you can't use the case statement -- then I guess you could use nested inner joins to solve the problem -- but that would be silly since you can use CASE.

Answer (score 0):

This is close -- there might be typos or syntax errors since you don't give some example data and I don't have an easy way to test right now.

But I think this makes it clear what the professor wants you to do -- iron out the details yourself.

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.product = 'iPhone' AND year(payment_date) = 2016 
           THEN p.purchase_call ELSE 0 END) AS q1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.product <> 'iPhone' AND year(payment_date) = 2016 
           THEN p.purchase_call ELSE 0 END) as q2,
  SUM(p.usage_winnings) as q3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.computer_usage = 0 THEN p.purchase_call ELSE 0 END) /
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.computer_usage = 1 THEN p.purchase_call ELSE 0 END) as q4 ,
  MAX(CASE WHEN p.purchase_call >= 2 THEN pa.payment_date ELSE null END) as q5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pa.payment_type = 'D' THEN pa.amount ELSE 0 END) -
  SUM(CASE WHEN pa.payment_type = 'W' THEN pa.amount ELSE 0 END) as q6
FROM USER u
JOIN USAGE us ON u.user_id = us.user_id
JOIN PRODUCT p ON us.product_id = p.product_id  
JOIN PAYMENT pa ON u.user_id = pa.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying get a better understanding of the syntax, but for `year(payment_date) ` wouldn't I need to specify which table the payment_date comes from. Like this `pa.payment_date`? And `p.purchase_call` does not exist in the product table. I switched it to `us.purchase_call`

Comment: My university's network is down right now, but I'm trying to make the most of the downtime still and get a better understanding of the code. I will test it with real data when the network is back up! @Hogan